# UITableView less than full screen from code?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ipad

I have a number of views that use UITableView.  (I use UIViewController and implement UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource interfaces.)  I'm having trouble creating a tableview that leaves room at the top for a toolbar. How to I size and layout the Tableview so that it is less than full screen?  Is this an AutoResizing mask problem?

Thanks,
Gerry

Comment: Show how you're creating the table views.

Comment: Where exactly would you put this code? I am having a similiar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the table view frame to size for the toolbar.  For example, you would run something like the following:

```
CGRect tableFrame;
tableFrame.origin.x = 0;
tableFrame.origin.y = toolbarReference.frame.size.height;
tableFrame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width;
tableFrame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height - toolbarReference.frame.size.height;
tableviewReference.frame = tableFrame;
```

This calculates the coordinates and size minus the toolbar at the top and then sets the frame of the tableview to those coordinates.