# Cant delete the cells  behind the iphone keyboard?

Tags: iphone

In a tableView, when I am in edit mode, I present a keyboard for the user to type, but I also want him to be able to delete the cells.

The problem is, when the keyboard appears, I cant access the cells at the bottom of the table, even If i scroll up, it goes back, so I can delete cells that I can see and those which I can scroll and see, not the extreme ones.

So shall I reduce the height of the tableView till the top of the keyboard ?
If yes, How do I accomplish it ?

Answer (score 0):

To set height of UITableview you can use following:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2908129/200272

Also solution to similar problem to your's has been described in:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/494028/200272

And to get information about keyboard size checkout official docs:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Kind regards,
Bo

Comment: But the thing is, how do I know where does the keyboard starts ?